# How to do bulk oracle data insert in web application (JSP)?

Tags: oracle, jsp, bulkinsert

I created jsp web apps to perform 4 millions data insert. The insertion process using loop from another table, so i did select query -> loop -> insert to other table, but everytime i run this, the page load slowly an ended with timeout. So not all data was successfully inserted

I had tried to use bul data insert, it didnt hep me.

btw this is the sample code :

```
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertquery);
                    pstatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("promo"));
                    while (rset.next()) {
                       pstatement.setString(1, rset.getString(1));
                      pstatement.setString(2, request.getParameter("promo"));
                        pstatement.addBatch();
                   out.print(rset.getString(1) + " Added<br>");
                       if (++countbatch % batchSize == 0) {
                          pstatement.executeBatch();
                       }
                     }
                    pstatement.executeBatch();
```

Another try using select trick, it also didnt help

```
String insertquery = "INSERT INTO datapin (msisdn,nama_promo)  SELECT  msisdnlist.msisdn AS msisdn, ? AS nama_promo  FROM msisdnlist ";
                    pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertquery);
                    pstatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("promo"));
pstatement.executeQuery();
```

Anyone have better idea ?? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it required that the jsp page waits for the 4M inserts to complete?
I think waiting for a long lasting operation is always tricky in a web app.

You might start a thread in the request handler that will do the inserts async.
The request handler could return a token.

Then this token could be used by a second JSP page to periodically check the status of the thread.